# An unfamiliar way of writing supersymmetry transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, chern-simons-theory

This question is in relation to this [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0680).

- I would like to know how the so called supersymmetry transformations at the start of page 27 or at the end of page35 (equation 8.4) or at the end of page 37 (equations 9.8,9.9,9.10) of the above paper are obtained.

I have never seen any supersymmetry transformation look like that!

I would be glad if someone can help me derive these transformation equations.

- Also if anyone can explain the meaning of the conjectures being made about some sort of "cohomology" in the tables on page 28 and 31.

I have tried to check these conjectures on my own in some simple cases. (by almost blind-foldedly using the supersymmetry transformations!)

- Can anyone suggest possible methods of trying to prove these conjectures or if there exists other papers with similar content?
- Is this what is called "quantum cohomology" ?

Answer (score 2):

As to your question on quantum cohomology, one can define it as a structure arising through chiral rings in super yang mills theory, as a deformation of the ordinary cohomology of a Kahler manifold through instanton corrections.